# Change drag speed in Qt

Tags: qt, qml, drag

How to change drag speed in qml. This means, when move mouse in horizontal line. The red rect move slower than below code:

```
        Rectangle {
        x: 10; y: 10
        width: 20; height: 20
        color: "red"

        Drag.active: dragArea.drag.active
        Drag.hotSpot.x: 10
        Drag.hotSpot.y: 10

        MouseArea {
            id: dragArea
            anchors.fill: parent

            drag.target: parent
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess there is no such term as _drag speed_. The drag point is the same point as the mouse one. The reason for visual artifacts is that QML repaints the rectangle when its position changes. To avoid that you can move the rectangle on drop event and use some mouse icon instead white dragging.

Comment: wanna use `MouseDevice` with change `sensitivity`, but this is for 3D environment. Maybe dynamic `dragThreshold` can!! 

Answer (score 0):

Check out SmoothedAnimation QML Type.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-smoothedanimation.html

Comment: Wanna drag in y axis and add `Behavior on y { SmoothedAnimation { velocity: 200 } }` in `Rectangle`. But not any make sense!

Comment: then, check out the source code of Drag attached property and MouseArea::drag group property. The thing is, if it sets x,y directly instead of using magical `obj->setProperty("x", ...)` method, then Behavior (property interceptor) won't have a chance to interfere.

Comment: In that case, another layer of indirection is needed. Use transparent element as a drag target, and the real other one follow its position — but declaratively, through QML property bindings. Add behavior on properties of a real one, and it should work.